# Is there any fast way to find the power of 2 nearest to a large given number?

Tags: java, math, time

I tried doing it in fastest way possible but have dead end. Please shed some light.

```
private static int nFind(long n) {
        long a,t = 0;
        for(long i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            t = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
            a = n/t;
            if(a==1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return (int) t;
    }
```

Time Complexity is the issue.

Comment: Could you not stick to a language instead of spamming on all these tags?

Comment: Hint: a power of 2 has only one bit set in it's binary representation.

Comment: wouldn't you already have the given number in binary (e.g. 10101), so you just check the same-length binary representation of a power of 2 10000... and the one above (100000) that for nearness?

Comment: If you want Java, you can check [`Integer.highestOneBit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int)).